# How to find count of positive and negative values in a row of dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r

```
      Loss1.       Loss2.         Loss3
     -456.             -2345.         -1290
       345.           -342.            234
```

I want to calculate how many times positive and negative value occurs in a row. Expected output is as follows

```
      Loss1.      Loss2.      Loss3.   Neg_count.  Pos_count
      -456.       -2345.      -1290.        3.                  0
       345.         -342.          234.         1                  2
```

I tried with rowsums,but it gives me sum of rows. How can I do it in r?

Comment: `df$Neg_count <- rowSums(df > 0)` then `df$Pos_count <- length(df)-df$Neg_count-1`.

Answer (score 6):

The code below should work:

```
dat <- data.frame(Loss1=c(-456,345),Loss2=c(-2345,-342),Loss3=c(-1290,234))
dat$Neg_Count <- rowSums(dat[,c("Loss1","Loss2","Loss3")]<0)
dat$Pos_Count <- rowSums(dat[,c("Loss1","Loss2","Loss3")]>0)
dat
 Loss1 Loss2 Loss3 Neg_Count Pos_Count
1  -456 -2345 -1290         3         0
2   345  -342   234         1         2
```